# What are the four types of relations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Wikipedia says the following:

> Relations are classified into four types based on mapping of elements.

However my textbook *Applied Discrete Structures* says nothing of the sort.

Is the Wikipedia article referring to the properties exhibited by relations, such as *symmetric*, *reflexive*, *transitive* etc.?

Are relations thus classified into types based on their properties or are their 'types' just their properties?

Comment: What article exactly says that? The page on binary relations doesn't contain the quote. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation

Comment: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics) (I didn't realize it was 'Simple' Wikipedia when I posted this question)

Comment: Wow, what a poorly-written Web page. It seems to be a collection of bits and pieces, many of them incomplete, some not even written in proper English (simple or otherwise). We can guess what was meant by the part you quoted, but at best it will be merely a good guess.

Comment: @DavidK, I didn't even realize it was 'Simple Wikipedia', when I posted this question, I apologize if this question was vague as a result.

Comment: It is OK for it to be "simple". The page just also happens to be unclear. That is not your fault, and it was OK to ask about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't really say, but I'd guess that they are using the following classification:

1. One-to-one relations,
2. Many-to-one relations,
3. One-to-many relations,
4. Many-to-many relations.

Note that the first two are actually functions (with the first being an injective function).